# Github public repo

Tags: git, github

I am new to **Github** and I am working on **CRM** for a company. Sometimes I work in my office and others in my home personal PC.

I decided to use **Github** so that I could always edit my files from any place without copy and pasting the **CRM** on each device everyday.

But the problem is that I couldn't hide that repo from people.. I mean it is public so anyone can **download** and **see** my code.

Also I don't want to buy and upgrade my membership on Github..

Any good solutions?

Comment: A good solution would be not copying source code willy-nilly as it might very well be grounds for termination to effectively reveal source code to the outside world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other repo and provide private repo, ex [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [Gitlab](http://gitlab.com)

Comment: Gitlab will help me have private repo for free?

Comment: @user7431257 Yes, both services provide free private repos.